# PHP foreach table transposed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I just cant seem to get to the bottom of foreach looping..

I have a table:

```
ID   Col1   Col2    Col3   Col4...
001  some   data    to     display
002  more   info    to     display
....
```

And I would like to dynamically build a table that shows as the below but for only 1 searched row...

So if the search matches ID=2 then you would get:

```
ID    002
Col1  more
Col2  info
Col3  to
Col4  display
...
```

The number of rows in the result would come from the number of columns read.

At the moment I am having to use a horrible fixed rendering which will not be dynamic if the number of columns in the data change.

```
    echo '<table class="main"><tr><th colspan="2">Component Information for '.$sheetData[$key]["A"].'</th></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["A"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["A"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["B"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["B"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["C"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["C"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["D"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["D"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["E"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["E"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["F"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["F"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["G"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["G"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["H"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["H"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["I"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["I"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["J"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["J"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["K"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["K"]. '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1]["L"]. '</td><td></td><td>'.$sheetData[$key]["L"]. '</td></tr>';
```

Help,  I just cant get my head around the looping....

Comment: You are looking for pivot tables. If your data are coming from Mysql you will find thousands of answer on how to build a pivot table from mysql. So you will get an array already set up properly and you will just need to do a foreach trough it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** I understand what you are trying to do, you could loop through the `$sheetData[$key]` and use those key to pull all of your `$sheetData[1]` items in the left-side of the table.  I am not sure how clear my explanation is, but it would look something like this:

```
// echo your one-time, static html
echo '<table class="main"><tr><th colspan="2">Component Information for '.$sheetData[$key]["A"].'</th></tr>';

// looping through should produce the same output as your example and handle dynamically-sized arrays
foreach($sheetData[$key] as $subKey => $subData) {
    echo '<tr><td>'. $sheetData[1][$subKey]. '</td><td>'.$sheetData[$key][$subKey]. '</td></tr>';
}

// close the table
echo '</table>';
```